# Android - RecyclerView ID mismatch with SQLite DB row ID

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm creating a recyclerview with the data of Title,message. I want to delete an item in the list. But list position mismatch with DB Table ID(column). ID is immutable, listview position changed everytime.

What is the solution to deal this problem? How can I create a custom ID in DB or How can I allocate the position of listview as per DB ID?

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) generic adapter

Answer (score 2):

> How can I allocate the position of listview as per DB ID?

You can't rely on the position.

You have ids 1,2,3 in positions 1,2,3 and you delete id 2, you now have ids 1,3 at positions **1,2**.

> I'm creating a recyclerview with the data of Title,message

You need to store an ID with that data. You don't need to show it in the Recyclerview, but each element does need it.

You should be able to store this value with the ViewHolder.

You can also try to implement `getItemId(int position)` to always return you a valid ID for any given position.

For example, [`CursorRecyclerAdapter`](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b)
(credits to @pskink)

Comment: shame on you cricket, CursorRecyclerAdapter was my idea ;-)

Comment: Thnq.. Bt position starts with 0. How can I handle?

Comment: @Shunmugapriya use a custom `CursorRecyclerAdapter`

Comment: Thnx for the idea. Im a beginner of Android. Let me try it.